# How to change the XAxis used on my chart ShinobiCharts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, charts

I'd like to have the xAxis of my chart to look like this :

Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, ..... Nov, Dec

Right now it's following it's default, numbering xAxis according to the number of Data Points.

How can i achieve this change to this axis ?

I've tried using Category Axis and setting an NSMutableArray containing these strings ("Jan", "Feb"...) as categories and  with a numberRange going from 1 to 12 but it didn't work.

```
chart = [[ShinobiChart alloc] initWithFrame:chartEmbaixo.frame withPrimaryXAxisType:SChartAxisTypeCategory withPrimaryYAxisType:SChartAxisTypeNumber];

NSMutableArray * monthNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Jan", @"Fev", @"Mar", @"Abr", @"Mai", @"Jun", @"Jul", @"Ago", @"Set", @"Out", @"Nov", @"Dez", nil];

SChartNumberRange * numberRange = [[SChartNumberRange alloc] initWithMinimum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]andMaximum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12]];
SChartCategoryAxis *xAxis = [[SChartCategoryAxis alloc] initWithRange:numberRange];
xAxis.categories = monthNames;

chart.xAxis = xAxis;
```

Comment: Any news on this? I want to achieve the same result...

Comment: Did you get this working ? Even I am looking for something similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first i use as my x axis

**Edit** how i make my x axis:

```
SChartNumberRange *r1 = [[SChartNumberRange alloc] initWithMinimum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] andMaximum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
SChartCategoryAxis *xAxis = [[SChartCategoryAxis alloc] initWithRange:r1];
xAxis.title = @"";
//xAxis.enableGesturePanning = YES;
xAxis.enableGesturePanning = YES;
xAxis.style.gridStripeStyle.showGridStripes = NO;
xAxis.style.majorGridLineStyle.showMajorGridLines = NO;
```

when you make you data points it should use the xValue as the x axis point. 
like this:

```
dp.yValue = 1000;
dp.xValue = @"Jan";
```

the xValue should be set as the x point for that particular data point. This should work, but if it doesn't or you want to do something more complex you can extend this method from  `SChartDelegate` protocol:

```
-(void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart alterTickMark:(SChartTickMark *)tickMark beforeAddingToAxis:(SChartAxis *)axis
```

in this method you have the `tickMark.tickLabel`is the axis label for that given point where you can do your editing. Don't forget to verify what axis your on.

Hope this helps. If not tomorrow i can post you some code from my project (currently i don't have access to it from where i am)

**Edit:** currently i have this code:

```
- (void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart alterTickMark:(SChartTickMark *)tickMark beforeAddingToAxis:(SChartAxis *)axis {
    if (chart.yAxis == axis ) return;
    for (UIView *i in tickMark.tickMarkView.subviews)
        [i removeFromSuperview];

    tickMark.tickMarkView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, 75);
    //center the marker at the right place because the size was changed
    tickMark.tickMarkX = tickMark.tickMarkX - (tickMark.tickMarkView.frame.size.width/2) ;
    tickMark.tickMarkY = 10;

    //img
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"graph_bar_tag_2@2x.png"]];
    img.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, tickMark.tickMarkView.frame.size.width, tickMark.tickMarkView.frame.size.height);
    [tickMark.tickMarkView addSubview:img];

    //label with the markView's size with 7px padding on the left and on the right
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 7, 5, tickMark.tickMarkView.frame.size.width-14, 15)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //tikMark.tickLabel has an pair of indexes so that i can easily find the data for this particular data point and series.
    label.text = [_dataSource getNameFor: tickMark.tickLabel.text];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    //color_other_light is a UIColor var
    [label setTextColor: color_other_light];

    [tickMark.tickMarkView addSubview:label];
...
}
```

Comment: Hmm I'm trying or code right now. I'd already tried to use xValue to set the labels for my xAxis, however if I do that, the chart is unable to recognize said month as a point on the xAxis where the Column should be placed

Comment: It looks like the chart is expecting "1, 2, 3, 4... 12" and when i set the xValue to @"Jan", @"Feb".... @"Dec" it is unable to place the columns in the right places..

Comment: i do `dp.xValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", seriesIndex,dataIndex ];` and if i don't do any thing else it shows me that string. i'll edit the answer above to show how i create the x axis

Comment: You don't have to set it's categories ?

Comment: i dont use categories. also I've looked at the demos in the trial pack that come with shinobi charts and there is a example called ColumnChart, if you look there they also dont use categories.

Comment: Hmm I see, I'm doing exactly as you've suggested, there must be something else in my code that's relating to SChartNumberAxis that's conflicting with the SchartCategoryAxis I'm trying to use, I'll dive in a bit more and see if i can sort this out, I believe your answer should be enough to solve this problem :D Will mark it as correct as soon !

Comment: My friend, I'm having a problem with something related to this topic, think we could have a fast check to see if you could help me with this ? I promise it won't take more than a few minutes of your time ! It's really tough to find discussions related to ShinobiCharts

Comment: I have 2 kinds of charts, one minimized and another one on a bigger scale, since my chart is displaying the name of all months which have data related to them, when i have data for all 12 months, the minimized charts has it's labels clustered, I was trying to control how many labels are displayed but couldn't find a way to do so with my CategoryAxis...

Comment: hum have you tried this code `SChartNumberRange *r1 = [[SChartNumberRange alloc] initWithMinimum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] andMaximum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]]; SChartCategoryAxis *xAxis = [[SChartCategoryAxis alloc] initWithRange:r1];` with this you will set a range where you will only see the 6 bars at a time, then you can set `xAxis.enableGesturePanning = YES;` to use swipe gestures to scroll to se the rest.

Comment: The chart itself has a good size, it's smaller but the user is stil able to see clearly all columns, the smaller charts work more like a summary of all kinds of charts you have available, the only problem here are the labels which have 3 chars each, if i have all 12 months with date, it's 36 characters being presented as labels on a small view :/ isn't there a way to just set a few of these labels as not visible ? (not all labels, just a few of them)

Comment: or at least change their font size to a much smaller one

Comment: hmm only way i can think of is you have to hard code that using the method i mentioned on my answer: `-(void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart alterTickMark:(SChartTickMark *)tickMark beforeAddingToAxis:(SChartAxis *)axis`. you will have to check if you want to hide it (eg: more them 3 bars) and do `tickMark.hidden = YES;` or `tickMark.tickLabel.hidden = YES;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20891/discussion-between-thiagocfb-and-hugo-alves)

Comment: sry for the delayed answer have you set the delegate for the event something along the lines of `yourChart.delegate = yourDelegateClass;`  yourDelegateClass has to use the protocol `SChartDelegate`

Comment: I'm using SC in MonoTouch. I need to set up an image in x axis. So, I I've overridden this method but it seems that `tickMarkView` is `null` (`nil`). Could you share other details on this? Thanks.